# Effective resistance in finite grid of resistors

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

Consider a $m\times n$ grid of one-Ohm resistors. What is the effective resistance of any given edge? I understand how to do the case $m=2$ inductively using the series and parallel laws, but I get stuck in breaking apart the grid for $m,n>2$ to allow for the application of those rules. There seem to be good considerations of the infinite grid (such as [this physics.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/401210/298897)), but I am specifically interested in a finite grid. Is there a way to truncate the some infinite series arising in the infinite grid case to give the answer for the finite case?

Comment: By 'any given edge' do you mean "between any two given points"? (That is: If I inject a 1-amp current at one point it and it all comes out at another, what is the voltage difference?) This has been considered in the literature previously, e.g., http://www2.ece.rochester.edu/users/friedman/papers/TCAS1_20_Mirror.pdf

Comment: I will also note the following Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance. (Whether this is useful computationally is another matter...)

Comment: Sure, that would be sufficient, but what I am most interested in is the effective resistance of just the edges (so adjacent vertices, the ones connected by the resistors themselves). Of course if there was a formula for any pair of vertices on the grid, I would gladly just specialize to the edge case, but it's possible that there is some exploitable symmetry for the case of the edges themselves. I will take a look at this paper, thank you for linking it.

Comment: @Semiclassical yes unfortunately the wikipedia page doesn't seem to have the tools to handle this kind of graph.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't provide an analytical answer, I can show how to compute these distances using Mathematica. The Wikipedia page for [resistance distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance) supplies the following definition:

> On a graph $G$, the **resistance distance** $\Omega_{i,j}$  between two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ is $$\Omega_{i,j}:=\Gamma_{i,i}+\Gamma_{j,j}-\Gamma_{i,j}-\Gamma_{j,i},\text{ where } \Gamma = \left(L + \frac{1}{|V|}\Phi\right)^+,$$
> with $^+$ denoting the Moore–Penrose inverse, $L$ the Laplacian matrix of $G$, $|V|$ is the number of vertices in $G$, and $\Phi$ is the $|V|\times |V|$ matrix containing all $1$s.

(I will not attempt to prove the equivalence of this definition to the physical one, but I've checked its efficacy for a few different cycle graphs.) While this doesn't itself lead to a simpler closed-form expression for resistance in a grid graph, this is sufficient to calculate the matrix $\Omega$ in Mathematica:

```
{m,n}={5,6};v=m*n;
g=GridGraph[{m,n}];
G=Transpose[Inverse[N[KirchhoffMatrix[g]+1/v]]]; (* aka the Gamma matrix *)
Clear[R];R[i_,j_]:=R[i,j]=G[[i,i]]+G[[j,j]]-G[[i,j]]-G[[j,i]]; (* aka the Omega matrix*)
```

(Note that Mathematica refers to the graph Laplacian as the Kirchoff matrix, and that scalar addition acts element-wise on matrices.) As an example, suppose we want one vertex to be the top-right corner of a 5-by-6 grid. Taking into account index conventions that I don't entirely follow, this requires $m=5,n=6,i=26$. So we take the 6th row of $\Omega$ (the R-array in the code) and reshape to get a 5-by-6 array:

`ArrayReshape[Array[R,{v,v}][[26]],{n,m}] //Transpose //MatrixForm`

```
0.698639    0.794557    1.04434     1.31814 1.68018     0.
0.563464    0.893328    1.15266     1.43951 0.659125    0.766115
0.961786    1.15983     1.4069      1.07386 1.02159     1.11488
1.25945     1.48398     1.40347     1.273   1.30368     1.42064
1.64818     1.78479     1.56339     1.55515 1.67139     1.96114
```

Thus the effective resistances for the edges at the upper-right corner are 1.66018 and 0.766115 respectively. This can be graphed using the `ArrayPlot` command (or `MatrixPlot` depending on your taste):

`ArrayReshape[Array[R,{v,v}][[26]],{n,m}] //Transpose //ArrayPlot`

[image]

Note that the resistance rises monotonically as one moves away from the source vertex, as it should if resistance is a valid distance.

One additional caveat: while the above code is tidy and generalizes to other graphs, that doesn't mean it's at all optimized. In particular it doesn't scale well with the number of vertices: a 50-by-50 graph takes about 1.3 seconds in Mathematica (via Wolfram Cloud), while a 56-by-56 graph takes about twice as long. Moreover, the matrix $L+\Phi/|V|$ appears to be ill-conditioned for large grids and so `Inverse` ceases to be effective. So the above implementation is likely only satisfactory if the graph is not especially large.

Comment: Thanks. One comment on speed: Mathematica's `Inverse` method is seemingly much faster than `PseudoInverse`, and since the graph here will always be connected, `Inverse` is adequate since adding the $\Phi$ term makes the eigenvalue of the trivial eigenspace be nonzero, thus making the matrix to be (pseud)inverted actually properly invertible.

Comment: @zjs After some testing, I entirely agree. (This was partly occluded initially due my initial code accidentally forcing Mathematica to compute the inverse symbolically rather than numerically. The code runs much faster now.)